# Marginal Density Function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Problem:

> For $y=e^x$ where $f_X(x) = e^{-x}$, $0 \leq x < \infty$, determine $f_Y(y)$.

I started to solve this from:
$$f_X(x) = \int f(x,y)\,dy
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
f_Y(y) = \int f(x,y)\,dx.$$
Buw how do I find $f(x,y)\,dy$ from these statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there exists a function $g$ such that $x=g(y)$ then the probability density of $y$ is given by the transfomation: $$f_Y(y) = f_X(g(y)) \left|g'(y)\right|$$

In this case $y=e^x$ implies $x=\ln y$ so we have such a function.

$$f_Y(y) = f_X(\ln y) \left|\frac{\mathrm d \ln y}{\mathrm d y}\right| \quad\text{with the support of: } e^0\leq y\lt \infty$$

Can you complete from here?

---

This transformation is obtained from the chain rule, when using an invertible function $g$.

$$\begin{align}
f_Y(y) & = \frac{\mathsf d F_Y(y)}{\mathsf d y} & \text{by definition}
\\[1ex] & = \left|\frac{\mathsf d F_X(g(y))}{\mathsf d y}\right|
 & \text{since } \mathsf P(Y\leq y) = \mathsf P(X\leq g(y)) \vee \mathsf P(Y\leq y) = \mathsf P(X\geq g(y))
\\[1ex] & = \frac{\mathsf d F_X(g(y)}{\mathsf d g(y)}\left|\frac{\mathsf d g(y)}{\mathsf d y}\right| & \text{chained}
\\[1ex] & = f_X(g(y)) \left|g'(y)\right|
\end{align}$$

Comment: Is the answer e^-ln y / y

Comment: @A_Sakir yes, but you can simplify it further, as $y^{-1}\,e^{-\ln y}=y^{-2}$.

Comment: This answer is like a shortcut. The question uploader should learn where this 'mystery' equation comes from....

Answer (score 2):

The first step in a question like this is always to determine the domain of the random variable $Y$. In this case that is $[1,\infty)$. Now choose $y$ in this domain. Then
\begin{equation}
F_Y(y) = P(Y\le y) = P(e^X \le y) = P(X > \log(y)) =\,\,...
\end{equation}
etc. Differentiate the answer to get the density. Do you think you can handle it from here?

Comment: +1 for giving the straightforward answer that _teaches_ the OP how to solve the problem instead of mindlessly applying the canned formula.